# Efficient way to find the source code of a given dialog in Java

Tags: java, ide, search

I am working on a Java app with some 100K lines code base. Searching for the source code of a given dialog is tedious. Searching by text is impractical because dialog title and button names are very short: "save", "yes", "no". There are hundreds of hits in the project. Besides, some of the dialog labels are not hard coded, but are retrieved from a config, to make interface more flexible. Other labels are retrieved from a DB.

I see three easy ways it can be implemented:

Firefox has "view selection source". Such feature in IDE would solve the problem.
Going to right dialog, enabling all break points in the project, pressing the button would hit break point in a right place.
Temporary attaching UUID to each string and search for the UUID in the source code will help to find the element.

Is there an easy way to find the source code of a given dialog window using NetBeans or Eclipse?

Comment: [Where does my tool question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7253/where-does-my-tool-question-go)

Comment: A modal dialog in java creates a nested event loop. Break in the event thread while it is open and scan the stack where it enters your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way. One would usually search for strings corresponding to name of dialog titles or buttons ("save", "cancel" are deal breakers) . If you can't find it - see ic an alias was used instead.

Answer (score 2):

Run your code in the debugger and put a deactivated break point *on the code that opens dialogs generally*. Then, immediately before you trigger the alert you're interested in, activate the break point. The stack trace will tell you exactly who opened that dialog and under what circumstances.

Comment: This is a manual process. Is there a way to automate it? I mean, you can find selection code by opening the whole html page in a NotePad and searching for text. But they managed to add "find selection source" to automate it. Do coders still search for Java code manually?

Comment: You don't know where *any* of your dialogs originate?

Comment: @sixtytrees This is a workaround for bad code structure (or being unfamiliar with the codebase). Automating workarounds is not really something you should consider in most cases.

Comment: @Kilian Foth I agree. And a browser is a workaround for people who can't read html. The problem is you don't really choose the code base.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do this. You might search by the text fragments appearing in it. Sometimes titles are storied in a separate config file. In this case you should find that file because it will help a lot to locate relevant code in future.